# Insert Building Blocks through Office JS API

Tags: office-js, office-addins, cpu-word

I'm new to Office Add-ons and I'm trying to figure out how to insert predefined [building blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/working-with-word/working-with-building-blocks) in MS word add-ons by using the js API. I can't find any mentioning of building blocks in the documentation for the office js API but only for VBA. Therefore I'm wondering if this function is missing from the API. My questions would be:

Is there any way to insert an existing building block into a document through the office js API? If possible I'd also like to add new building blocks through js API.

The overall goal is to create an add-on that provides buttons to insert a building block. I can do it in VBA but I want to avoid getting too deep into the API before realising that the project is not possible there.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. BuildingBlocks are not yet supported in the Office JavaScript library. You will not be able to work with them programmatically in an Office Web Add-in.